# Using Laravel's pluck method without an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array, pluck

Let's say I've got an `Article`s collection, and I want to fetch the popular articles.

So first, I make a `scopePopular()` method in the `Article` method. Very simple.

Now I want to fetch their `id`s, so I'll do this:

```
Article::popular->pluck('id');
```

The result will be an associative array:

```
[
    0 => 1,
    1 => 34,
    2 => 17
    ...
];
```

I want to get a normal array, without the keys, Like:

```
[1, 34, 17]
```

I know I can just do something like this:

```
array_values(Article::popular->pluck('id'));
```

But I believe Laravel has much more cleaner way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing in php. All arrays have their indexes. There is literally no difference between [0=>1, 1=>34] and [1, 34].

Answer (score 8):

All arrays have indexes.

```
[
    0 => 1,
    1 => 34,
    2 => 17
];
```

equals to

```
[1, 34, 17]
```

In other words:

```
$a1 = [0 => 1, 1 => 34, 2 => 17];
$a2 = [1, 34, 17];
$a1 === $a2;
// returns True
```

Comment: You're right. the issue I had was because of my bad approach to the structure of the array. Thanks for clarifying it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-values) method which is wrapper for [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
Article::popular->pluck('id')->values();
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions

Answer (score 0):

Its exactly what you need and what you get, By default php has the incremental key from 0.

You want to see something like a JSON array I assume.
Just do a return the array and you will see the JSOn array in browser, but internally its like this only.

Please confirm and let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$store_type = \App\Websites::find($request->store_id)->first()->store_type;
```

// Outputs - just a string like "live" // there was option like a demo, live, staging ...

It might be useful for someone else.